# Importing azure blob via SAS in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

EDIT:
I am looking to import a blob from an `Azure Storage Container` into my Python script via a `BLOB-specific SAS`.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

sas_service = BlobService(
    account_name = "name",
    sas_token = "mytoken"
)

blob_content = sas_service.get_blob_to_path("container_name", "blob_name")
```

I tried using this, but it outputs an `OSError` listing also a "503 error"

Comment: What type of SAS token is that? An account SAS? A container-specific SAS? Also: what do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Did you get an error message? Right now, as written, this question is unclear. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Hint: 503 is an HTTP status code. Get to googlin'

Comment: You edited your question to mention a blob-specific SAS. That would be the core of your problem. You're trying to initiate the blob service client with a SAS that has nothing to do with service-level authentication.

Comment: Would you please post more details such as error log to let me help you to solve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description , you want to `access azure blob storage` via `SAS_TOKEN`.

You could refer to the snippet of code as below which works for me:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService,
    ContainerPermissions,
)

accountName = "<your_account_name>"
accountKey = "<your_account_key>"
containerName = "<your_container_name>"
blobName = "<your_blob_name>"

def GetSasToken():
    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
    sas_token = blobService.generate_container_shared_access_signature(containerName,ContainerPermissions.READ, datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
    return sas_token


def AccessTest(token):
    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name = accountName, account_key = None, sas_token = token)
    blobService.get_blob_to_path(containerName,blobName,"E://test.txt")


token=GetSasToken()
print token
AccessTest(token)
```

You could also refer to more details from [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: where sas_token is Query string that you have created from the portal  Storage Explorer (preview) - > Shared Access Signature - > Query string

Comment: `BlockBlobService` is no longer part of `azure.storage.blob` library. What is the new method for uploading blobs to a Container using SAS tokens?

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the suggestions mentioned in the below articles:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-python-getting-started/blob/master/blob_advanced_samples.py

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/commit/35c890c1de66f3cf0cf44f3cc405d61912c8054b

[How to use Azure Blob storage from Python](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/blobs/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage.md)

Comment: Please don't post answers that just contain links to tutorials or documentation, as this isn't a valid answer.