# Azure-blob-storage. Get access to container with SAS token

Tags: python, azure, sas-token

I'm trying to get access to blob storage container, this is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerSasPermissions

blob_storage_account = 'account name'
blob_storage_container = 'container name'
blob_storage_key = 'account key'

permission = ContainerSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, delete=True, 
                                 list=True,delete_previous_version=True, tag=True)

token = generate_container_sas(account_name=blob_storage_account,
                        container_name=blob_storage_container,
                        account_key=blob_storage_key,
                        permission=permission,
                        expiry='2050-2-25')

url = f'https://{blob_storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(url, credential=token)

container = blob_service_client.get_container_client(blob_storage_container)
container.list_blobs().next()
```

But I get this error when I use the list_blobs().next() method:

```
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure 
the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:42251c89-501e-0056-5156-0af114000000
Time:2021-02-24T02:41:46.8149241Z
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
Error:None
```

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value), and they refer to reset or adjust the time zone, but that didn't work

Comment: I think that this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910151/importing-azure-blob-via-sas-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `expiry='2050-2-25'` is incorrect, it needs to format as UTC time like "2021-02-24T15:33:13Z".

By the way, you could get container_client directly with `ContainerClient.from_container_url(...)`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerSasPermissions
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

blob_storage_account = ''
blob_storage_container = ''
blob_storage_key = ''

permission = ContainerSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, delete=True, 
                                 list=True,delete_previous_version=True, tag=True)
sas_token = generate_container_sas(
        account_name=blob_storage_account,
        container_name=blob_storage_container,
        account_key=blob_storage_key,
        permission=permission,
        expiry='2021-02-24T15:33:13Z'
    )
print(sas_token)

url = "https://"+blob_storage_account+".blob.core.windows.net/"+blob_storage_container
container_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(
    container_url=url,
    credential=sas_token
)
container_client.list_blobs().next()
```

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, yes. That was the problem. Thanks Pamela. Regards